# Textures get a pink hue but only when displayed far away, or at some angle

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, texture2d, voxel

Here's a video showing my issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4a1tQUn0HA

- I'm using the URP pipeline
- No fog
- No antialiasing. I had it turned on previously, and when I got really close to my cubes, I could see what seemed like a 1px gap between the textures, with some purple. But when I turned off antialiasing, it disappeared. https://i.stack.imgur.com/erlM8.jpg

Any idea on what to tweak to fix that? If you need a screenshot of any of my settings, let me know.

Comment: What is your texture format?

Comment: Have you tried other textures?

Comment: It's a png. I just found a workaround I guess: disabling Mip Maps. When I make my terrain huge, that's what happens: https://i.imgur.com/PaUYyg0.png. If I disable them, then it works. I read disabling them has an effect on performances tho, so I'll have to look into it more.

Comment: http://kylehalladay.com/blog/tutorial/2016/11/04/Texture-Atlassing-With-Mips.html I think this article is pretty good for those interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a **MipMap Bleeding** issue, this usually happens in atlassed textures, when the textures in the atlas are too close to each other thus creating mipmap artefacts. This issue is usually sorted by adding some *padding/dilation* when creating an atlass.